# How to include jar file into iphone application

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, ios, jar

Thanks in advance.

I want to include some jar file into my iphone application. Is it possible and is there a way to do that? If anyone knows please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no. You cannot include a **jar file** in your iphone application.
See [**this**](http://www.coderanch.com/t/484136/iphone/Mobile/Java-jar-file) also.

Answer (score 0):

I am NOT sure you can run Java or JDK in iOS...

**UPDATE:** on 16th Nov, 2012. As the world around us might come to an end (mayan myth) and iOS6 is rampantly used, still Java is barred from entering the iOS club. Why this 3rd world citizen treatment to Java, go figure...